# Running two LP heaters

Tags: hvac, heating, propane

recently ripped out the old oil furnace that was proving to be more trouble than its worth to fix ; and went and got a 30K BTU heater, BUT its only warming up one side of the house, I plan on getting another to put on the other side but my question is will both of those be able to run alright off of my 100LB tank? and If so any rough estimate of how long?

Comment: I do hope that they have Oxygen deficiency minoring devices on them. Can in some instances cause dangerously low levels of life sustaining oxygen.

Comment: they shut off if the oxygen is low

Comment: Current, indoor-rated ones do have [O2 deficiency systems](http://thermablaster.com/why-thermablaster/vent-free-heaters/how-vent-free-heating-work/). I have one that has no such feature, and I'm careful how I use it in enclosed spaces. (I believe the problem is not actually that people might not get enough oxygen, but that in low-oxygen conditions the burners can start making deadly CO.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 100lb propane tank holds approximately 24 gallons of fuel, each of which will provide about 90k BTUs. So, one of your 30k BTU/hour heaters will use 1/3 gallon of fuel an hour (if run at full tilt), using up the full 100lb tank in about three days.

reference: https://theadminzone.com/threads/propane-usage-calculations.118427/